# Where to execute extra logic for linq to entities query?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let say that I want to populate a list of CustomerViewModel which are built based on Customer Entity Framework model with some fields (like Balance) calculated separately.

Below I have code which works for lists - it is implemented in my service layer, but also I want to execute this code when I just get one item from the database and execute is as well in different services where I'm accessing Customers data as well.

How should I do this to ensure performance but to to not duplicate code - the one for calculating Balance?

```
public List<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModelList()
{
    IQueryable<CustomerViewModel> list = from k in _customerRepository.List()
    select new CustomerViewModel
    {
        Id = k.Id,
        Name = k.Name,
        Balance =
        k.Event.Where(z => z.EventType == (int) EventTypes.Income).Sum(z => z.Amount)
    };
    return list.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in you business (service) layer:

```
private List<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModelList(IQueryable<Customer> customerList)
{
    vaar list = from k in customerList
    select new CustomerViewModel
    {
        Id = k.Id,
        Name = k.Name,
        Balance =
            k.Event.Where(z => z.EventType == (int) EventTypes.Income).Sum(z => z.Amount)
    };
    return list.ToList();
}

public List<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerViewModelListForAllCustomers
{   
    return GetCustomerViewModelList(_repository.List());
}

public CustomerViewModel GetCustomerViewModelListForOneCustomers(int id)
{   
    return GetCustomerViewModelList(_repository.List().Where(c => c.Id == id)).First();
}
```

`_repository.List()` must return IQueryable.